# Having a trouble in detecting an error In a code that gets 10 numbers in input, and gives their sum at output.

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm trying to write a code that receives 10 numbers in input and gives the sum of them at the output, for some reason the code works on every 10 numbers, but when I insert the number 1 as first input and number 2 as second input, it doesn't work. and it gives me the following message:

[image]

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i, sum = 0, value, numbers_to_read;
printf("Please enter number of values\n");
scanf("%d", &numbers_to_read);
for( i = 0; i < numbers_to_read; i++ ) {
printf("Enter the next integer: ");
scanf("%d", &value);
sum = sum + value;
}
printf("The sum of the %d numbers is %d\n",
numbers_to_read, sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What the Downvoting is for ?

Comment: nothing wrong with code.. it gives expected result.

Comment: @JerryGoyal did u see the black picture? When after I enter 2 the program stops!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I compiled and ran your program, told it 1 number, then entered the number is 2, sum of that one series of numbers is 2.Just like your screen image, expect I run it from console and don't get the prompt to continue.

Comment: Downvoted. The program works perfectly.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani Do you see the picture? It asks you how many numbers you want to enter and you say "1".

Comment: [Works with 5 numbers too](http://ideone.com/vX9e5J).  It appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: so because people found that everything was right you are downvoting? this is not fair!

Comment: @WeatherVane Apparently all of you see that Im new here and im getting used to the bureaucracy here and nature of questions. thanks for showing much support :)

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani  Your program works *exactly* as you intend it to. If you expect different output, please edit your post and say so, including details.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani "When after I enter 2 the program stops!" is incorrect.  The code read the `2` with `scanf("%d", &value);`.  The loop `for()` loop is now complete as it was told to only iterate 1 time, not 10.  Then the code printed `printf("The sum of the...`.  _then_ the code stopped.

Answer (score 2):

"when I insert the number 1 as first input and number 2 as second input, it doesn't work"

```
scanf("%d", &numbers_to_read); //input is 1
for( i = 0; i < numbers_to_read; i++ ) { // loop runs 1 time
printf("Enter the next integer: "); 
scanf("%d", &value); //value entered is 2
sum = sum + value; //sum = 0 +2
}
```

therefore output is 2 indeed.